# Use ul li twice in html5

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am using ul li in my nav but also to make a notice board. But I want to separate the ul li elements. Is there an easy method like nav ul li {} and notice board ul li{}

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: sure, just add a class/id to your notice board/nav and target it in your css .class or #id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define CSS class for both of them. For example:

```
.nav {
  /*some css*/
}


.notice_board {
  /*some css*/
}
```

and then link them to desired HTML elements

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li>...</li>
 ...
 <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

for navigation and

```
<ul class="notice_board">
 <li>...</li>
 ...
 <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

for notice board.

Comment: That  fix that problem but I have a problem with ul li :hover,ul li a :focus how do I separate them in the nav and notice board I have tried putting nav and notice board in front of them.

Comment: .noticeboard ul li a:hover,ul li a:focus{
  box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;}

Answer (score 0):

You could use [nav tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp) with just links instead of a list for nav. Keep in mind that you might need to add some extra code if you care about IE8. I tend not to care that much in new projects.

Comment: I have href for links its just I used ul li to make a notice board or borrowed it off the net and worked it for myself. Problem they are both ul li. The .nav and .noticeboard works so fat need to break down the hover anf child class